# Refining a type with declaration merging

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library that has an interface as follows:

```js
interface Foo {

   metaData: { [k: string]: any }

}
```

The metaData object is a place to store arbitrary keys and values.

My application always populates part of this object, lets say it always provides a 'title' property.

Using declaration merging, I would like to specify this globally. I *think* this is not possible with Typescript, but wanted to make sure.

```js
declare module 'my-lib' {
  interface Foo {
    metaData: {
      title: string,
      [k: string]: any
    }
  }
}
```

This is invalid syntax, but I'm curious if there's a way to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you'll have to modify the library (that is, use a locally-maintained version of its typings).